# For a Euclidean Domain, prove that $\delta(z)>0$ if $z\in R$ is not a unit.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, unique-factorization-domains

For a Euclidean Domain, prove that $\delta(z)>0$ if $z\in R$ is not a unit, where $\delta$ is the Euclidean function.

Is it just since $z$ is not a unit then $\delta(z)>\delta(1)>0?$

Please help, thanks!

Comment: You should also exclude $z = 0$.

Comment: Okay. so if $z$ is non zero and not a unit, then $\delta(z)>\delta(1)$. But how is $\delta(1)>0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write $1=aq+r$ with $r\ne 0$ (otherwise $a$ would be invertible), so $0\le\delta(r)<\delta(a)$.